# How can my Raspberry PI start my TV?

Tags: hdmi

My Raspberry Pi is running RaspBMC and is hooked up to my TV via a HDMI cable. I never turn off the Pi itself, but I tend to turn the TV off when I'm not using it. However, once the Pi senses any input (key-down etc), it turns my TV on.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would guess that when you say you *turn the TV off* you are using the remote control to do so, not the switch at the wall.

Most TV's don't actually *turn off* with the *off button*, they just go into [standby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standby_power) mode. This allows them to monitor your remote control so that they can sense when you command the TV to turn back on again via the remote.

In the same way, many TV's will monitor input signals (HDMI, Scart etc.) and turn themselves on when a new signal is received. I suspect that what is happening is that when the Raspberry Pi is coming out of sleep, it starts sending a video signal to the TV again, bringing it out of sleep too.

Alternatively, as [Krzysztof suggests](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1744/141), Raspbmc may be commanding the TV to turn on via the [CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC) protocol channel, so you may be able to disable it.

According to the [HDMI CEC and XBMC](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=2485&start=50) thread on the Raspberry Pi forums, the [libCEC FAQ](http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/faq) explains how to do this:

> Where can I find the CEC adapter's settings in XBMC?
>
> - Go to System -> Input -> Peripherals -> Pulse-Eight CEC Adapter.
>
> What's the meaning of the CEC adapter's settings in XBMC?
>
> - Enabled: use the CEC adapter within XBMC. Default: Enabled.

Of course while the upside of *off* meaning *standby* is convenience, downside is that the TV consumes power even when it is *off*.

Answer (score 8):

This may be possible because of [CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC). RaspBMC supports CEC and I believe it's enabled by default.